# Is the date here true for live bitcoin and altcoin prices?

Tags: litecoin, buy-bitcoins, exchange-rate

i found this site: http://coinmarketprice.com
Its pretty easy to navigate i like it.
Are the list there true for market caps of the coins and are the live prices for bitcoin and other altcoins are latest data?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the prices are live and up to date.

Check this one out and compare them
http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/currency/USD.html

That's real time incl. BTCchina and other non-USD markets.

Well, if you need multi-coins prices, the USD price should be averaged somehow and you probably use the right tool to track them all.